# A paradox in special relativity, about relativistic rigidity

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

A certain man walks very fast, so fast that the relativistic length contraction makes him very thin. In the street he has to pass over a grid. A man standing at the grid fully expects the fast thin man to fall into the grid. Yet to the fast man the grid is much narrower even than to the stationary man, and he certainly does not expect to fall in. Which is correct?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_paradox

Answer (score 1):

I am happy to be corrected by others if necessary, answering this question will be a good test of my understanding of Special Relativity.

Firstly, you cannot have a stationary man; only a man (or woman!) who is stationary relative to something else, either an observer or a reference frame. In this case stationary with respect to the grid. So let us call him the grid man G. Then the fast man is F.

Now when F travels at speed close to c, he does not become thinner (alas or you could make a fortune with health remedies!). F is only seen to be thinner from another reference frame, in this case the frame used by man G. Man G does not however conclude that F is thinner because he has studied relativity, G knows that F appears thinner due to the velocity, and he can calculate the real dimension of F using the Lorentz Transformation. So he concludes that F will not fall into the grid.

Comment: So if G did not study relativity then F would have fallen through the grid?

Comment: Serious answer: G only observes F to be thinner. If G was travelling with F (co-moving) he would observe what is called "Proper Time and Proper distance" and F would be his normal size. However I am wondering about this now because muons from cosmic rays should not be able to arrive at the Earth's surface due to their short decay time. But they do arrive because time dilation at their high velocity increases the duration for which the muon exists before decaying. So perhaps the relatavistic length and time can cause a different event.

Comment: Lambda may have intended his reply as a joke, but it does have similarities to the Copenhagen interpretation of  Quantum Theory where the event which happens depends on when an observation was made, as with Schrodinger's cat, which is both alive and dead until the observation.